# How to integrate Magento with Oracle? How to create adapter/interface for the same?

Tags: oracle, magento, interface, integration, adapter

I wanted to know how to integrate Magento with Oracle apps??

So for this, we need to write adapter/interface to sync Magento with Oracle??

Anybody who has already done this or having any idea how to do this...plz guide me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Use Magento Enterprise Edition 1.11 or greater and ask Magento for the Oracle resource helpers.

Comment: Ben, Could you give me more information regarding the Oracle Helper ?

Comment: I cannot, but your sales rep at Magento can.